# Argument of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the argument of $2+i$, $\tan \theta=\frac{1}{2}$, but not getting anything. 
How would I find this?

Thanks

Comment: What's keeping you from taking the next step after having $\displaystyle \tan (\theta )=\dfrac{1}{2}?$

Comment: @GitGud I was looking for an exact value, not a decimal.

Comment: You don't know what $\displaystyle \arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is, is that it?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using the unit circle but it's not working. Unless I am overlooking the obvious

Comment: You can use Tangant, sine, or cosine tables and then come up with general forms. Also you can use arc-tan to refer to the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost done. Take $\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac12$ to get the principal argument, since $2+i$ lies to the right of the imaginary axis.

Comment: Can I get an exact value?

Comment: $\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac12$ *is* an exact value. It isn't a nice fraction of $\pi$, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh okay, that's what I thought, but wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything.

Comment: Don't be scared of the arctangent! Imagine someone saying "I have found that $x = \sqrt(3)$, but I don't know where to go from here!" ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $z=x+iy \to  tan\phi=\frac{y}{x}$

[image]

Comment: The OP already figured out that much.